# Creating different symbol for & at GET request

Tags: php

Currently, I've a script that is working perfectly! And I must use GET parameters at my situation, and unfortunately, my old smart tv still not able to recognize **&** symbol

e.g:

```
http://localhost/share.php?code=161494581&nativo=sim&url=http://cdn100.ntncc.stream/prop/httpdelivery/14004787mega.mp4&mediaType=fixit&mediaName=Mega&mediaClose=2000&idfy=1
```

In my smartv, the link stop at the first & symbol. So, I'll use a different symbol, like **|**

```
http://localhost/share.php|code=161494581|nativo=sim|url=http://cdn100.ntncc.stream/prop/httpdelivery/14004787mega.mp4|mediaType=fixit|mediaName=Mega|mediaClose=2000|idfy=1
```

And I'm trying to create a script to split all | symbol and after this, split = symbol to attribute the name to the respective value.

Here is my PHP script:

```
$string = "https://<private-urk>/player/share.php|code=161494581|nativo=sim|url=http://cdn100.ntncc.stream/prop/httpdelivery/14004787mega.mp4|mediaName=Megatubarão|mediaClose=2000|idfy= 1";
$split1 = explode('|', $string);


$arr = [];
foreach ($split1 as $value) {
    $split2 = explode('=', $value);
    $_GET[$split2[0]] = $split2[1];
    echo $_GET[$split2[0]];
}
```

The script is not working, it's showing wrong the values, I've no idea about what I should to. Can you help me?

Comment: You can add urlencode() function at the source. You can avoid many other special chars by that..

Comment: Still not working, I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just replace the `|` with `&` again, strip out the URL and then use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$string = "https://topflix.tv/player/share.php|code=161494581|nativo=sim|url=http://cdn1.ntcdn.stream/prop/httpdelivery/filmes/p1/14004787megatubarao-2018.mp4|mediaType=filme|mediaName=Megatubarão|mediaYear=2018|idfy= 1";
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, '|'));
parse_str(str_replace('|', '&', $string), $_GET);
print_r($_GET);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [code] => 161494581 
    [nativo] => sim 
    [url] => http://cdn1.ntcdn.stream/prop/httpdelivery/filmes/p1/14004787megatubarao-2018.mp4 
    [mediaType] => filme 
    [mediaName] => Megatubarão 
    [mediaYear] => 2018 
    [idfy] => 1 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AiuMu)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
$string = "https://topflix.tv/player/share.php|code=161494581|nativo=sim|url=http://cdn1.ntcdn.stream/prop/httpdelivery/filmes/p1/14004787megatubarao-2018.mp4|mediaType=filme|mediaName=Megatubarão|mediaYear=2018|idfy=1";
$split1 = explode('|', $string);

foreach ($split1 as $value) {
    $split2 = explode('=', $value);
    if(isset($split2[1])){//check value
    $_GET[$split2[0]] = $split2[1];
    echo $_GET[$split2[0]];}
}
```